# Sum of products of all subsets,

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials

I want to calculate sum of product of every subset of given $N$ element set. For example, given set {1, 2, 3}, the answer is 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 3 + 2 * 3 + 1 * 2 * 3. I also would like to give the answer modulo $M$.

What I know is that I could calculate $(x - a_1)(x - a_2)...(x - a_n) - 1$, but that would involve FFT, so there could be some rounding errors, but the main problem with that idea is that it takes $O(N \log^2 N)$ time and doing modulo $M$ is problematic. Is there any faster way to solve this problem? It is not my homework, I got this task from my teacher to practice to the programming contest but I really got stuck on this problem.

Constraints:

$a_i \le 10^9$

$N \le 10^6$

$M \le 10^9$

Comment: 1. Please provide attribution to your sources.  Can you edit the question to state the specific source where you got this problem from?  2. We want to help you understand, not just do your practice problem for you.  Doing your practice problem for you would help neither you nor anyone else.  In particular, the only way you get better at this is by working through it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum in question is

```
[(1+a_1)*(1+a_2)*(1+a_3)*...*(1+a_N) - 1] (mod M)
```

This is

```
[(1+a_1)%M * (1+a_2)%M * ... * (1+a_N)%M - 1] % M
```

I would be surprised if you could do much better.

Here is a Python implementation:

```
def sumProducts(nums, M):
    p = 1
    for num in nums:
        p = p*((1+num)%M)%M
        if p == 0:
            return M-1
    return (p-1)%M
```

The optimizations from the naïve formula I gave above were to take the modulus of the product with each new factor and to short-circuit the product if a zero is encountered -- which will happen if the prime factors (counting accorded to multiplicity) appear in the `(1 + a_i)`

A simple test:

```
>>> sumProducts([1,2,3],5)
3
```

which is easily verified by hand.

A stress-test:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> nums = [randint(1,1000000) for i in range(100000)]
```

`nums` is a million random numbers in range 1 to a million

of course,

```
>>> sumProducts(nums,2**32)
4294967295
```

since there are at least 32 odd numbers in `nums` (hence 32 numbers `a_i` for which `1+a_i` is even).

on the other hand, 1000003 is a prime number which is greater than 1000000, so the computation doesn't short-circuit:

```
>>> sumProducts(nums,1000003)
719694
```

The computation takes than a second.

Comment: This is linear O(N), so unbeatable. (Take the modulo after each multiply to avoid overflow.)

Comment: Very elegant, short sweet and simple

Comment: @YvesDaoust I regarded the part about taking the modulus at each step to be clear from context, though it is certainly a good idea to make it explicit. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnColeman: due to the spacing you used, one is lead to think that the modulo just applies to the immediate left argument. You can parenthesize `(...((1+a_1)%M * (1+a_2))%M * ... * (1+a_N))%M`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are correct that in the formula as written there is nothing about taking the modulus at each step (since that would require deeply parentheses) but the `%M` on the end makes it clear that the entire product is computed mod `M` with it being an implementation detail that to compute this efficiently you take the modulus at each step. On the other hand, what seems obvious to someone familiar with modular arithmetic might not be obvious to all, so it is good to be explicit about this detail.